# How to open a wav file from the user's directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

hope you all are okay. I need to open a wav file from the user's directory, I'm getting the right directory, but when it tries to read the audio file with the soundfile library the program shuts down.

Any idea how can I fix that?

```
class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            uic.loadUi("Ambisonics.ui",self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abrirarchivo)
      def abrirarchivo(self):
            nombre_archivo = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Abrir Archivo Ambisonics format B','/Users/cristianpedraza/Desktop/','Archivos WAVE (*.wav)')
            nombre_archivo = nombre_archivo[0]
            print(nombre_archivo)
            print(type(nombre_archivo))
            [datos, Fs] = sf.read(nombre_archivo)
```

Thanks a lot for helping me, have a wonderful day.

Comment: It's possible the file is too large. How big is the file? Does it work for small files? Please also include code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please post the error as well.

Comment: Well there is no error, I'm using Qt5 and Python to create an interface and when a push the button the application just shut down. The function connected to this button is just like the post.